# How can I set up Openlayers to use backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openlayers

I am trying to build an app based on Openlayers and backbone.js.  Should i make each layer a view? So far i have a Map View, marker view and was thinking about making each layer a view as well.  I have a markers model and map model.  Can anyone help me out with setting this up?

Answer (score 4):

After doing it similarly to @Gagan's answer in the past, here's how I would do it next time:

Treat the OpenLayers Map as a special rendering surface - different from the DOM, similar to how you would treat a `<canvas>`.  Recognize that Backbone makes some (light) assumptions around the idea that your views are rendered in the DOM:

1. There is a special relationship between Views and their corresponding DOM node (`view.el` and `view.$el` magic).
2. The `events` hash is automatically translated into handlers for events triggered on the DOM node.

We will want to recreate these concepts for our OpenLayers views.  Some ideas:

1. In Backbone, the View is the mediator between a model and a piece of the DOM. In OpenLayers, instead of a piece of the DOM, we have an OpenLayers Feature, Vector, Marker, Popup, whatever.  We could recreate this special relationship between the View and its OpenLayers object.  The view listening to model changes and updating the OpenLayers object comes naturally.  What about listening and responding to events on the OpenLayers object?

This is one of the sticky parts of OpenLayers.  Let's say you have a `SelectControl`. You can listen to events at the layer level, which will give you a reference to `event.feature`.  But how do you map that feature back to your view to keep good separation of responsibilities?  Pick your poison.  In my examples below, I will (re)trigger the event directly on the feature, which the view already has a handle to.  Then the view will have to listen to those events on the feature.  Note that OL features don't have events built into them. We will mix Backbone events into them using `_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);`.

1. You could create a featureEvents hash, but that might be over-engineering.  Views already receive a model object and explicitly bind to its events.  In my examples below, I'll do the same thing for the OL Feature that my view creates.

Now for structuring your Views.  I tend to think of an OpenLayers `Layer` as a *collection of items*.  Let's say you want to render a collection of features. You might create a `FeatureCollectionView` class that is initialized with a `Map` object.  It would then create a `Layer` for its collection.

```
FeatureCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        // requires options.map, an OpenLayers Map object.
        // requires options.collection, a FeatureCollection object.
        options = options || {};

        this.map = options.map;

        this.initLayer();
        this.initSelectControl();

        this.collection.on('add', this.addFeatureModel, this);
        this.collection.on('remove', this.removeFeatureModel, this);
        this.collection.each(this.addFeatureModel, this);

        // ...
    },

    initLayer: function() {
        this.layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('a collection of features', {/* options */});
        this.map.addLayers([this.layer]);
    },

    initSelectControl: function() {
        this.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(this.layer, {
            hover: true,
            multiple: false,
            highlightOnly: true
        });

        this.map.addControl(this.selectControl);
        this.selectControl.activate();
        this.layer.events.on({
            featurehighlighted: function(event) {
                // requires that you've extended your view features with Backbone.Events
                if (event.feature.trigger) {
                    event.feature.trigger('featurehighlighted', event);
                }
            },
            featureunhighlighted: function(event) {
                // requires that you've extended your view features with Backbone.Events
                if (event.feature.trigger) {
                    event.feature.trigger('featureunhighlighted', event);
                }
            },
            scope: this
        });
    },

    addFeatureModel: function(model) {
        if (!this.views) this.views = {};

        this.views[model.cid] = new FeatureItemView({
            layer: this.layer,
            model: model
        });
    },

    removeFeatureModel: function(model) {
        this.views && this.views[model.cid] && this.views[model.cid].remove();
    },

    // ...

});
```

Then we need a `FeatureItemView` that is initialized with an OL `Layer` to render itself on.

```
MyFeatureView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        // requires options.layer, an OpenLayers Layer that is already added to your map.
        options = options || {};

        this.layer = options.layer;
        this.initSelectControl();

        // ...

        this.render();

        _(this.feature).extend(Backbone.Events);
        this.feature.on('featurehighlighted', this.showPopup, this);
        this.feature.on('featureunhighlighted', this.hidePopup, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.feature = // ...

        this.layer.addFeatures([this.feature]);

        // ...
    },

    remove: function() {
        this.layer.removeFeatures([this.feature]);
    },

    // ...

});
```

---

I found some other interesting solutions by searching for discussions related to "backbone and canvas" since it has some similar aspects.

Comment: I just started with backbone, sorry for the simple question.  What is 'this' in the example?

Comment: `this` is the instance of the view, where `MyFeatureView` is the "class".  So after you do `var aView = new MyFeatureView();`, you can call `aView.render()`, inside which `this` refers to `aView`.  Does that help?

Comment: Do you have a model that represents the actual `map`? I was thinking `this.layer` referenced `map.layer`, but it looks like my assumption was incorrect

Comment: Do you have the example `Model` class that contains the OpenLayers map? I'm just trying to wrap my head around that initializer

Comment: Hey Tyler, I deleted my last comment and totally rewrote my answer.  Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite.  It makes more sense, but I've still got a couple sticking points.  I've started a gist so I can, hopefully, better show where my confusion is.  We are also using Marionette, so that may be adding to my problems: https://gist.github.com/workmaster2n/8976222

Comment: 2 questions: does the event hash do anything in `MyFeatureView` (I see you have to manually assign the callbacks later) and should `this.selectControl.events.on` be `this.layer.events.on`?  Thanks for the help, I'm getting pretty close to a working app

Comment: @TylerDeWitt Good catch on the `events` hash. That was left over from my previous answer and I've removed it now.  As for `selectControl.events` vs. `layer.events`, I see both in my code so maybe they're interchangeable?  Is it only working for you if you bind to the layer?

Comment: Yep, it only seems to work on the layer.  But once it's working, it's behaving beautifully.  Thanks for the help.  Extending backbone was a great idea

Comment: Glad I could help. I will change it to `layer.events` in my answer (and in my code). Don't forget to vote up any answers that were helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

This gist may help you. For understanding Backbone with OpenLayers its quite useful. 
https://gist.github.com/bwreilly/2052314